# Selecting numbers "larger" than a given number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL with one number column and I have a given number `x`.

If `x` is in the table, I want all numbers `>= x`.

If `x` is not in the table, I want all numbers `> x` and the largest number `< x`.

Example:

```
id 
5
10
15
20
```

For `x = 15` it should return `15` and `20`.

For `x = 12` it should return `10`, `15` and `20`.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id > 12
UNION
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name WHERE id <= 12
```

which works correctly.

Is there any single-query way? Thank you.

(This is just an example with single column and numbers. The reality is a larger table and datetime column, but the principle should be the same.)

Comment: This is a single query, so what's the problem?

Comment: Might try this, but I don't see why would you bother: `SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id >= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name WHERE id <= 12)`

Comment: I think he means without using two selects. Maybe you could do something like SELECT id,MAX(id) and then do some more filtering using the two conditions in the where clause.  You would have to devise a way to short circuit the second condition in the where clause as you wouldn't want results returned if the first part of the condition already returned results.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - I like this logic. It allows me to access other columns in the main query using just one subquery. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converted from my comment:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE id >= (SELECT MAX(id) 
                FROM table_name 
               WHERE id <= 12)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from A where id >= coalesce((select id from A where id = 13),(select id from A where id < 13 order by id desc limit 1));

select * from A where id >= coalesce((select id from A where id = 15),(select id from A where id < 15 order by id desc limit 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way using windows functions:

```
select id
from (select id, lead(id) over (order by id) as nextid
      from t
     ) t
where nextid >= 12
```